# Hide one wedge in a pie chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to hide one wedge of a pie chart in Matplotlib, but there does not seem to be an option for it in the parameters.

I guess it would be possible to give one bar the same color as the background but that doesn't feel like a reliable solution. Is there a better way?

Comment: How could I improve my answer to get your approval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate the visibility of any WEDGE in your pie chart.
E.g.,

```
In [36]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    ...: import numpy as np 
    ...: data = np.arange(5.0)+2.0 
    ...: wedges, labels = plt.pie(data, labels=['a','b','c','d','e']) 
    ...: wedges[3].set_visible(False) 
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image]